# example using django-proxy?

Tags: django

Have you used [`django-proxy`](http://bitbucket.org/montylounge/django-proxy/)? Can you give me an example of when it would be a good idea to use it? Thanks.

Comment: In particular, I wonder if it's still relevant in light of the addition of Proxy Models in 1.1. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blog engine [Mingus](http://github.com/montylounge/django-mingus), which I use for my blog, includes django-proxy to allow you to post items of different content types - blog posts, quotes, etc - but have them all appear on the index page in a similar format.

In response to Hank's comment, this is a completely different thing to 'proxy models' - those are for subclassing a model without creating a new table, in order to change some specific functionality rather than any actual fields. This has nothing to do with what django-proxy does.

Comment: Umm... like generics objects?